# How can I measure the effectiveness of my Macro?

Tags: starcraft-2

Macro involves producing constantly, keeping your resources low and hitting the optimal production cycles. Having said that there is an optimal Macro for any given Build Order.

I want to know what the optimum amount of workers, army, production facilities and upgrades is for a given time, like @10:00 or @14:00.

Is there some kind of tool or map that allows me to test this? My macro is not perfect, so I cannot benchmark this on my own.

I searched the internet and found tools like [SCBuildOrderOptimizer](http://code.google.com/p/scbuildorder/) and [EvolutionChamber](http://code.google.com/p/evolutionchamber/) but they seem to work the other way around. You insert the worker count etc. and you get a build order that would get these specifications.

I want to specify a build order, assume that workers and units get produced all the time and I want to get the resulting unit count and upgrades etc.

Something like this:

1 Rax FE @10:00:

- 50 SCVs
- 100 supply
- Stim 95% (finishes @10:15)
- 1/0 90% (finishes @10:30)
- 2 Medivacs
- ...

Comment: So you want the SC2 version of [BWCoach](http://bwchart.teamliquid.net/us/bwcoach.php)?

Comment: I do not know this tool, but if it does what I specified: Yes.

Comment: Well BWCoach seems to coach you throughout the game, but I do not necessarily need that. I would also accept only a simple text output of the state of the game after an optimal execution. It would be nice though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most agreed upon measure of macro skill is the "spending quotient" statistic. It is strongly correlated with a player's league and thus with his ability to win. You can use [this calculator](http://acslayer.webs.com/) to determine your SQ for any particular game, or use a collection of your games to determine your average SQ. The author says this:

> Note that the SQ scale is not designed to be accurate for games with Income lower than 600 (partly because there is little demand on a player to spend well during the opening stages, especially if they are following a prepared build order). I recommend you use at least 10 of your own games with an Income of 600 or greater; the more games you use, the more accurate the figure will be.

You can find a full detailing of it [here](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=266019).

Comment: This is a good indicator. Even though it is not exactly what I was looking for I will accept it. Just to state why this is not optimal: Even if you skip or forget SCVs in your BO and build more Marines instead you can achieve very high SQ scores, but in the end your Macro is off.

Comment: If you do that it will dramatically lower your resource collection rate, which I believe will lower your SQ as well.